# Is it good idea to add word-wrap:break-word to body?

Tags: css, word-wrap

Can I run into some issues with this code?

```
body {
   word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

May be I should better add that rule to more specific selector?

**UPD**
I use it to solve problems with loooooooooooooooooooong words, that can appear anywhere and break layout.

Comment: What the hell are you talking about?

Comment: You could, in this case, ask a better question.

Comment: It depends solely on your design, nothing else. There are no specification-related obstacles to doing so.

Comment: @SvenBieder Sorry, I not good enough in english.

Comment: Please write what your problem is. Using word-wrap itself is no problem...

Comment: @SvenBieder I use it to solve problems with loooooooooooooooooooong words, that can appear anywhere and break layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looking at the comments in this issue of [boilerplate/github](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/issues/947), using `word-wrap:break-word;` on `html` element has no particular drawbacks but it seems to have significant effects only on links element.

Anyway to avoid unpredictable issues I would prefer use it only for `<a>` elements (just a matter of preference)

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not a good idea, because it may break words arbitr
arily. If some occasional long strings are your problem,
analyze them and decide on some reasonable approach (e.g.,
URLs can be handled in special ways, but on the other hand
you should avoid putting URLs into text).